# Gradle how to use a project that is on an upper hierarchy?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have the following repository structure (there is a `build.gradle` under every project, and a `settings.gradle` under `my-project`):

```
my-project
|
├── my-shared-project-A
└── my-project-B 
    └── my-project-C
        └── my-project-D
```

I want to use `my-shared-project-A`, from `my-project-C` and `my-project-D`.
What is the syntax for this?

I've tried:
`my-project-D`

```
dependencies {
    implementation(":my-project:my-shared-project-A")
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a `settings.gradle` under `myproject`? How are the builds included?

Comment: Also, why are the projects nested like that? 

Comment: Yes, I do. I’ve added it, even though it’s pretty trivial. Such nesting totally makes sense on large projects.

Comment: Never seen it before...  Where did you add the settings.gradle?

Comment: At root, of course

Comment: This is how monorepo works

Comment: I have worked on them before. Just saying I've never seen this layout. Doesn't mean it's wrong, just that I've never seen it

Comment: As I've asked and as asked in the answer below, what are the _contents_ of the settings file. How are you including the builds?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you declare projects in `my-project/settings.gradle`

if it's `include('my-shared-project-A')`, then it would be `implementation(project(":my-shared-project-A"))`.

Mind the project() call.